# How can I play MusicXML file on Android?

Tags: android, android-music-player, omr, musicxml

Are there any existing tools or libraries for this? I am currently trying to develop an application that can take an image of a sheet music and make it to a musicxml format and play the corresponding audio. And I am stuck on how to exactly play an audio from musicxml.

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, but the SeeScore SDK will do this: http://www.seescore.co.uk/developers/seescore-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of JFugue can parse MusicXML.

There are Android ports of JFugue as well.

[jfugue.org](http://www.jfugue.org/)

[JFugue-for-Android](https://github.com/kshoji/JFugue-for-Android)